# Why does this method of computing the sign of an integer avoids branching on CPUs with flag registers (IA32)?

Tags: c, integer, bit-manipulation

In the below example ([source](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CopyIntegerSign)):

```
int v;      // we want to find the sign of v
int sign;   // the result goes here 

// CHAR_BIT is the number of bits per byte (normally 8).
sign = -(v < 0);  // if v < 0 then -1, else 0. 
// or, to avoid branching on CPUs with flag registers (IA32):
sign = -(int)((unsigned int)((int)v) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1));
// or, for one less instruction (but not portable):
sign = v >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
```

Could you please explain the latter 2 methods, especially the second one? Why does it avoid branching  on CPUs with flag registers?

Comment: `sign = -(v < 0);  // if v < 0 then -1, else 0. ` It's never `0`.

Comment: Obviously neither of these methods use a branch instruction. So I don't see why this would use a branch in _any_ CPU implementation. On X86, you would do that with a single assembly instruction, even a lot easier than these C instructions.

Comment: @PMF It's not at all "obvious" that the expression `v < 0` is branch-free. It certainly can be, and there's no obvious branch at the C level, but it's easy to imagine it compiling to a "`cmp/jmp/mov/jmp/mov`" sequence. The way I read it, the OP's code even assumes the first implementation to use branches.

Comment: It is very doubtful whether talking about registers when looking at C code makes sense. Indeed, gcc with optimizations compiles all three versions to exactly the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last method assumes that for a -ve signed integer, >> does an arithmetic shift.  This may or may not be the case -- the standard says it is "implementaton-defined".

The second method is making assumptions about where the sign-bit is (in particular that "padding" does interfere)... which is technically a mistake, standard-wise.  Worse, however is the cost of the shift -- unless the machine cannot do the first method without a jmp, in which case the shift may be faster.

So the question is, what does your compiler do with `-(v < 0)` ?  There are several ways on most processors to avoid a pipe-line crashing jmp, and one would hope that your compiler would select the best way... I would write this the obvious way: `(v < 0) ? -1 : 0` and let the compiler do its job.

When I had a look at what gcc (4.8) does (-O2) for `-(v < 0)` and for `(v < 0) ? -1 : 0`, both compiled to `sar $01f, %eax` on an x86_64.  This surprised me (see below)... but is the last method on your list.

However, I think the real message is to stop trying to second guess the compiler, and let it choose the best approach.

---

I used to make a living writing assembler, and (for x86) what I would have done is:

```
  add   %rax, %rax
  sbb   %rax, %rax
```

...however, gcc (4.8) -O0 gave me:

```
  shr     $01f,%eax
  movzbl  %al, %eax
  neg     %eax
```

...and -O2 gave me:

```
  sar     $01f, %eax
```

...so clearly gcc is less frightened of shifts (on an x86_64), than I am !  Using shifts avoids setting up any flags dependencies, which may help.  But what little information on instruction timing I can find suggests that shifts have become blindingly fast !  When I tried timing the `sar` version against `add/sbb`, the `sar` came out about twice as fast... so I can stop worrying about how long shifts take !

On the x86 (since the 386) the compiler could:

```
  test    %eax, %eax
  setl    %al
  movzbl  %al, %eax
  neg     %eax
```

or (since the Pentium Pro):

```
  test    %eax, %eax
  mov     $0, %eax
  mov     $-1, %edx
  cmovl   %edx, %eax
```

...so there are any number of ways of avoiding a conditional jmp.  But with the speed of shifts... all this is academic !

Your ARM can do almost anything conditionally, so `(x < 0) ? -1 : 0` can be done without branches.  I'm not an ARM expert, but I think `SBFX` will do the job in one instruction -- but I don't know how desirable that might be.  Obviously, the arithmetic right shift `ASRS` will also do the job.

Your PowerPC has instructions to load a general purpose register with the current flags... which would also avoid a jump.  But it too has an arithmetic right shift.

Anyway, this doesn't change my main conclusion, which is that it is not worth second guessing the compiler -- unless the compiler is rubbish, in which case the optimum solution may be to do explicit shifts... but that is likely to be processor dependent !

Answer (score 0):

The second to last method simply shifts the most significant bit (MSB) down to position 0 and then negates. The convention is that the MSB contains the sign of the number (1 -> negative, 0 -> positive). So for 32 bit numbers, this is equivalent to `-(v >> 31)`

I don't see how this could depend on "CPUs with flag registers", though.

The last one simply shifts the number. Since the original number is signed, the shift operation might (or might not) preserve the sign. The actual behavior depends in the implementation details of the C compiler (does it shift with sign extension or simply move bits). Let's look at the bit patterns (I'm using 8 bit numbers for better readability):

```
1000 0001
```

can be read as 129 (unsigned) or -127 signed. Shifting that to the right once can result in either:

```
1100 0000 (sign extending shift)
0100 0000 (logical shift)
```

which would represent the numbers -64 or 64 respectively. If you do a shift by 7 (or 31 for a 32bit number), you get `1111 1111` or -1.

The C standard doesn't explicitly state which type of shift the compiler has to support. In Java, there is are two shift operators for this reason (`>>` for sign extending shift or `>>>` for logical shift).

Comment: Second last method has nothing to do with conventions and no assumption except that unsigned int lacks padding. Otherwise it's purely unsigned arithmetic semantics which are fully defined.